# React: Logging state of a parent from a child component yields different results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to develop a component that has two columns: one from which you can add something to a list, and the other one in which you can see/modify items which are already added. I wanted to create a function that deletes the element from the list using `splice(index, 1)`, however, it was always deleting elements from an index to the end. I started debugging it, and I have a problem that I cannot solve. I pass a function as a prop that is suppose to log all elements in a state of a parent component.
Here is my code:

```
const ElementCreator = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  const addElement = () => {
    const elementsSlice = elements.slice();
    const newElement = (
      <Example
        position={elements.length}
        deleteHandler={handleElementDelete}
        key={elements.length}
      />
    );
    elementsSlice.push(newElement);
    setElements(elementsSlice);
  };

  const handleElementDelete = (position) => {
    console.log(elements);
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <Button onClick={addElement}>Add Example Element</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <div>{elements}</div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setElements([]);
          }}
        >
          Reset
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

const Example = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.position}
      <div>
        <Input type="checkbox" />
        <Input type="checkbox" />
        <Input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            props.deleteHandler(props.position);
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </Button>
        <Button>Move Up</Button>
        <Button>Move down</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Anytime I press the delete button, I get a different results. Here is how the console output looks like when I press each button:

```
[]
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 [{…}]
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 (2) [{…}, {…}]
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
react_devtools_backend.js:4049 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Can someone tell me why logging the same thing yields different result in each case?

Comment: Clarify if you are pushing only the delete button, or the add button as well.  You are slicing your elements, then adding an component with the current elements length (which you previously sliced in a variable), then you see the elements to a new array. So your Example component elements and current state elements are really never the same.

Comment: Why do you pass the `position` in, when you do nothing with it?

Comment: @TR3
I add elements with the add button, and then log it. But I dont understand, why are they not the same?

@Gh05d
I pass `position` because ultimately I would like to do something like:

`const elementsSlice = elements.slice();`
`elementsSlice.splice(position, 1);`
`setElements(elementsSlice);`

Comment: Keeping actual React nodes in state is one easy way to run into this problem. Instead keep only _data_ in state and build Nodes in your render function (like this https://jsfiddle.net/8c67xsyL/). The reason your version does not work has to do with JS variable scope and the way React works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with this code..

#1 you are assigning a variable to an array with an empty `slice` called on it (this could introduce bugs, and not sure why you would need to call this empty function)
#2 you are passing the length of the array, then you are wanting to delete something based on the `position` variable that is tied to the length of that array.

Array length != the last `index` of an array

arr = [0,1,2,3] => arr has a `length` of 4, but if you called arr[4] you would get `undefined`

You say you are clicking on the add button, your function is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing => adding an element to your current elements state array.

```
  const addElement = () => {
    const elementsSlice = elements.slice();
    const newElement = (
      <Example
        position={elements.length}
        deleteHandler={handleElementDelete}
        key={elements.length}
      />
    );
    elementsSlice.push(newElement);
    setElements(elementsSlice);
  };
```